# ODBC Logging of Requests

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

This article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?ppud=4 describes how to log SQL requests sent via ODBC.

Does anyone know the registry key to use for Access 2010?  I searched the registry and found an entry for TraceSQLMode in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\ODBC and turned it on.  I ran a few queries from Access out to a remote SQL Server instance, but then search as hard as I could, I couldn't find an sqlout.txt file.

I've searched the registry for another key, but can't find one.

Comment: The linked to article seems to have disappeared - which is a shame, it was quite a bible for me

Comment: Just checked again today.  The article referenced has been re-instated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\ODBC]
```

Values:

```
"TraceODBCAPI"=dword:00000000
"DisableAsync"=dword:00000001
```

**"TraceSQLMode"=dword:00000000**

```
"QueryTimeout"=dword:0000003c
"LoginTimeout"=dword:00000014
"ConnectionTimeout"=dword:00000258
"TryJetAuth"=dword:00000000
"FatBlastRows"=dword:ffffffff
"FatBlastTimeout"=dword:00000003
"AsyncRetryInterval"=dword:000001f4
"AttachCaseSensitive"=dword:00000000
"FastRequery"=dword:00000000
"ODBCISAMAttach"=dword:00000000
"PreparedInsert"=dword:00000000
"PreparedUpdate"=dword:00000000
"SnapshotOnly"=dword:00000000
"AttachableObjects"="'TABLE','VIEW','SYSTEM TABLE','ALIAS','SYNONYM'"
```

Comment: Thanks - worked a treat.  It took me a while to find sqlout.txt It didn't place it within the directory of the access file I had opened but rather the place before that I had run access from.  Strange

Comment: @akc42 I can't find `sqlout.txt` anywhere. I tried doing a non-indexed search on my hard drive. I also looked in the [default database folder](http://blog.dafran.ca/post/2011/09/20/MSAccess-(2003)-SQL-Trace-(TraceSQLMode).aspx). Man! Where is it?

Comment: @akc42 I wonder if it's [because of this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204(v=sql.90).aspx?ppud=4): `Office Access 2007 uses a customized version of the Jet database engine, named the Office Access Connectivity Engine (ACE), which is not shared with other Windows applications. If you are using Office Access 2007, navigate to the following registry key.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\ODBC` **I can't find the `Access Connectivity Engine` in my registry though.**

Comment: @akc42 :  **I figured it out!** [Trace ODBC commands from the Access Connectivity Engine (ACE) with SQLOUT.TXT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189062/trace-odbc-commands-from-the-access-connectivity-engine-ace-with-sqlout-txt/189063#189063)